# Combobox with 3 cells active

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, excel-2016

I have a big problem with making the Combobox in VBA Excel active.

My problem refers to the 3 separate list indexes, that I have to combine together.

Initially I was trying do like this:

```
Sub jan4()
    Sheets("1_GENERAL").Activate
    Range("A2").Value = ("=C4")
    Range("A5").Value = ("=D4")
    Range("B5").Value = ("=E4")
```

[image]

However this issue looks quite tedious across the whole year (365 repeats of these values for 1 combination only!). I have decided to make it with SpionButton and ComboBox

```
Private Sub SpinButton1_SpinDown()
    If Me.ComboBox1.ListIndex = -1 Then Exit Sub
    Me.ComboBox1.ListIndex = Me.ComboBox1.ListIndex - 1
End Sub

Private Sub SpinButton1_SpinUp()
    If Me.ComboBox1.ListIndex = Me.ComboBox1.ListCount - 1 Then Exit Sub
    Me.ComboBox1.ListIndex = Me.ComboBox1.ListIndex + 1
End Sub


Next rCell

For Each rCell In workseets("1_GENERAL").Range("d1:d366")
    ComboBox3.AddItem rCell.Value    
Next rCell

For Each rCell In Worksheets("1_GENERAL").Range("e1:e366")
    ComboBox3.AddItem rCell.Value
```

Whereas the range C,D,E 1:366 represents a single days throughout the year with values, that I would like to switch together via particular cells (A2 for range C1:C366; A5 for range D1:D366 and B5 for range D1:D366), from which further data processing is linked.

I have created the ComboBox linked with SpinButton, where I can easily select the date (range C1:C366), although this is only 1 thing, that I can do. Nothing changes. 
Could you help me how to make this ComboBox usable then?

Thanks & Regards,

Comment: Can you please check your VBA codes you posted in the question? They are somehow messed up or incomplete procedures.

Comment: Could you tell me what is messed up?
As long as I know only the last part of code doesn't work, because It was my trial to make it usable. Both 1st and 2nd part of the code with SpinButton works.

Comment: eg `Sub jan4()` as no `End Sub` and is therefore incomplete. Also all the code behind `Next rCell` is even not in a procedure and therefore cannot work. Also you cannot use `Next rCell` before a `For`. That's what I mean by messed up.

Comment: Thank you. Next time I will put a whole code. I obviously have    End Sub in my VBA sheet.